# Summation of Binomial Coefficients with geometric series

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}2^n$$
Hi Im trying to prove an identity with this sum being a key feature, I was wondering if there was a direct formula for the sum of this product. I know the sums for each of the products individually but not together.

Comment: Usually, $n$ and $k$ are reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the expansion of $(1+2)^k$, and the answer is $3^k$.